How to give user a role for certain time in discord.js?
so I'm making a little bot called "Prison". All it does is adds a command /jail which takes two arguments, username and time(days). I want the user to get the jailed role whenever I run the command and it automatically gets removed after the time given. I'm fairly new to discord.js.
I tried doing a setInterval but... It's very self explanatory why it didn't worked, because I can't track the time of however many different users with one setInterval.

My suggestion would be that you track the time and penalty duration in a database (most simple form just a json) and use a cron job to check like every 5 minutes if a player can be removed from the role.

A very basic example would use setTimeout():
const ONE_DAY_MS = 1_000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

const days = 3;
const daysToMs = days * ONE_DAY_MS;

member.roles.add(role);

setTimeout(() => member.roles.remove(role), daysToMs);

Keep in mind that the bot must not crash or reset before the time runs out.
